# Cannot upload files one by one using ng-file-upload. Streams limitation?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I used almost identical code from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/

I faced the following problem. On browser side I can see in debugging console that everything is good: if I sent 3 files I see 3 POST request with status 200. But inside "uploads" folder I can find only one (first) file.

I found out that server just cannot start receiving the next file before it saved the previous file. Looks like some kind of file-streams limitation. How to fix it?

Here is my actual code:

**Uploader:**

```
this.uploadFiles = function(files) {
        $scope.files = files;
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            file.upload = apiService.addFilesInDesk($rootScope.user.auth_token, $scope.deskData, file);

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                    evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        });
    };
```

**Requester:**

```
addFilesInDesk: function (authToken, deskData, attachedFile) {
        var randParam = _getRandParam();
        var upload = Upload.upload({
            url: config.apiLink + 'UploadDeskFile',
            data: {
                uploadfile: attachedFile,  auth_token: authToken,
                rand_param: randParam, key: _getRequestKey(randParam), desk_id: 1
            }
        });

        return upload;
    }
```

**Server side:**

```
public function actionUploadDeskFile()
{
    $return = array(
        'result' => 'failed',
        'error' => array()
    );
    $user = Users::model()->find('auth_token="' . $_POST['auth_token'] . '"');
    if ($user) {
        $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
        $modelFiles = new Files();
        $modelFiles->user_id = $user->id;
        $modelFiles->name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
        $modelFiles->link = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s-u') . '_crmFile_' . $user->id . '.' . $ext[1];
        $modelFiles->type = 'CrmFile';
        $modelFiles->save();
        $modelDeskFiles = new CrmDeskFiles();
        $modelDeskFiles->client_desk_id = $_POST['desk_id'];
        $modelDeskFiles->file_id = $modelFiles->id;
        $modelDeskFiles->save();
        $uploadDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/';
        $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
        copy($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile);
        copy($uploadFile, $uploadDir . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s-u') . '_crmFile_' . Yii::app()->user->id . '.' . $ext[1]);
        unlink($uploadFile);
    } else {
        $return['description'] = 'User does not exist';
    }
    Json::render($return);
}
```

Comment: does `$_POST` contain different data?

Comment: @messerbill, I need to extract from `$_POST` the data that I sent in Requester: rand_param, auth_token etc.

Comment: thats what i asked - when you debug serverside, does the content of `$_POST` change per request?

Comment: @messerbill, I have different values for `rand_param` and `key` each request, but the structure is the same. I affraid that PHP or Windows just reject the file if file writer (that writes file to disk) is busy at the moment. But I don't know anyway.

Comment: did you check for `$_POST['auth_token']` serverside?

Comment: @messerbill, yes. It is ok.